# Why does GetSystemInfo().minimumApplicationAddress return a number greater than GetSystemInfo().maximumApplicationAddress?

Tags: c#, memory

I am following a tutorial on how to manipulate memory, and for whatever reason, the following code gives 65536 for the minimumAddress and -65537 for the maximum address, which doesn't make much sense.

I would expect the maximum address to be greater than the minimum, since otherwise would mean there are no addresses.

[Here](https://codingvision.net/security/c-how-to-scan-a-process-memory) is a link to the tutorial I am following in case that helps.

```
SYSTEM_INFO sys_info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
GetSystemInfo(out sys_info);

IntPtr proc_min_address = sys_info.minimumApplicationAddress;
IntPtr proc_max_address = sys_info.maximumApplicationAddress;

// saving the values as long ints so I won't have to do a lot of casts later

long proc_min_address_l = (long)proc_min_address;
long proc_max_address_l = (long)proc_max_address;

Console.WriteLine("Min Addr: {0}, Max Addr: {1}", proc_min_address_l, proc_max_address_l);
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue, min address is 65536 and max address is 140737488289791

Comment: Is this maybe a bug or some security lock by windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sys_info.maximumApplicationAddress` changes based on Platform Type:
Any CPU: 0xfffeffff
x64: 0x00007ffffffeffff
x86: 0x7ffeffff

When doing a cast to long you are casting a 4 bytes signed value (int32) of 0xfffeffff which is -65537.

Since working with memory addresses there won't be any negative values so you can change to unsigned values.

IntPtr to UIntPtr

long to ulong

```
public struct SYSTEM_INFO
{
...
    public UIntPtr minimumApplicationAddress;
    public UIntPtr maximumApplicationAddress;
...
}

public static void Main()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sys_info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
    GetSystemInfo(out sys_info);

    UIntPtr proc_min_address = sys_info.minimumApplicationAddress;
    UIntPtr proc_max_address = sys_info.maximumApplicationAddress;

    // saving the values as ulong ints so I won't have to do a lot of casts later

    ulong proc_min_address_l = (ulong)proc_min_address;
    ulong proc_max_address_l = (ulong)proc_max_address;

    Console.WriteLine("Min Addr: {0}, Max Addr: {1}", proc_min_address_l, proc_max_address_l);
}
```